# Android - Unable to Close AlertDialog with In-App Billing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, in-app-billing

I am having a problem with an AlertDialog that I am using to initiate an In-App Purchase. When the user taps the "Buy" button, the In-App Purchase fires as expected, but the AlertDialog does not close. Then, when the In-App Purchase finishes, the program returns to my app but the AlertDialog is still open.

If I comment out the buyCard() function, the AlertDialog will close. Any idea why the AlertDialog is not closing when the In-App Billing is involved?

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Buy","Close"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Card.this);
builder.setTitle("Want to Buy?");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        if(item == 0) { // BUY THE ITEM
            dialog.dismiss();
            buyCard();
        } else if (item == 1) { // Don't Buy
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this question has long been figured out, but the probable solution would be to move `buyCard();` to above `dialog.dismiss();`

So, like this:

```
    if(item == 0) { // BUY THE ITEM
        buyCard();
        dialog.dismiss();
    } else if (item == 1) { // Don't Buy
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Reason being, the dialog can't run the `buyCard();` line since you've already dismissed it.  Kind of like trying to run code after a `return` statement.